# Use a generating function to determine the number of different election outcomes from 25 voters choosing from four candidates?

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions

I know I need to find the coefficient but I'm just not sure on how to start.

Comment: What do you define as an "outcome?" I only see four different outcomes: candidate one wins, candidate 2 wins, candidate 3 wins and candidate 4 wins...

Comment: I'm assuming it means how many different ways can the 25 voters vote for 4 candidates.

Comment: Perhaps in this way candidate one gets $k$, candidate two $l$, candidate three $m$, candidate four $n$ votes. So the question might be the next: in how many way can we scribe  $25$ in the form $k+l+m+n$? In this case I suggest to the asker the first chapter of the  famous problem book edited by Pólya and Szegő.

Comment: Ahhhh it can be a partition problem! Thanks!

Comment: Are you specifically asked to use generating functions to solve this?